# Conditional Table row in angularJs

Tags: html, angularjs, html-table, conditional-statements

I have angular display some tables with data from a JSON file.

```
<div class="inner">
    <div ng-controller="Picks">
        <element>
        <th><b></b></th>
        </element>
        <table id="myTable" class="tablesorter">
            <thead>

                <tr>
                    <th style="width: 70px">League</th>
                    <th style="width: 150px">Away<br>Home
                    </th>
                    <th style="width: 130px">Score</th>
                    <th style="width: 200px">Game Clock</th>
                    <th style="width: 200px">Wager</th>
                    <th style="width: 100px">Amount</th>
                    <th style="width: 100px">Odds</th>
                    <th style="width: 90px">Result</th>
                    <th style="width: 80px">Net</th>
                    <th style="width: 100px;">Game Date</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
            <tbody ng:repeat="i in picks" style="height: 50px; left: 50px">
                <tr style="border-top: 1px solid #000; text-align:left">
                    <td rowspan="2" style="width: 70px">{{i.league}}</td>
                    <td style="width: 150px">{{i.teamName[0]}}</td>
                    <td style="width: 30px">{{i.teamScore[0]}}</td>
                    <td rowspan="2" style="width: 100px">{{i.quarter}}</td>
                    <td rowspan="2" style="width: 200px"><b>{{i.pick}}</b></td>
                    <td rowspan="2" style="width: 100px">{{i.units}} Unit(s)</td>
                    <td rowspan="2" style="width: 100px">{{i.odds}}</td>
                    <td rowspan="2" style="width: 80px">{{i.result}}</td>
                    <td rowspan="2" style="width: 80px">{{i.net | number}}
                        Unit(s)</td>
                    <td rowspan="2" style="width: 100px; text-align: center">{{i.time}}</td>
                </tr>

                <tr style="text-align:left">
                    <td style="width: 150px">{{i.teamName[1]}}</td>
                    <td style="width: 30px">{{i.teamScore[1]}}</td>
                </tr>


                <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
function Picks($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('http://xxxxxxxx/Service/picks').
        success(function(data) {
            $scope.picks = data;
        });
}
```

Now what I want to do is, if there exists a pick2 property in the json, then create another tr and display some information.

How can I create this conditonal HTML row?

The JSON is shown below, sometimes there will be a pick2, and a pick3. When they exist, Id like the units2, odds2, result2, etc associated with that pick to be displayed on my table:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
    <tbody ng:repeat="i in picks" style="height: 50px; left: 50px">
            <tr style="border-top: 1px solid #000; text-align:left">
                ....
            </tr>
             <tr ng-show="i.pick2 !== '' && i.pick2 !== undefined && i.pick2 !== null">
              ...
           </tr>
  </tbody>
```

This way you can display tr conditionally.

Comment: This will also repeat the tbody for each set also - thats not great

Answer (score 1):

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/c4pdTibSdSRJeIGGWYxp?p=preview)

If you have a table structure like this:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
           <th>Name</th>
           <th>Description</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="row in rows">
            <td>{{row.name}}</td>
            <td>{{row.description}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And you want to conditionally display another row depending on whether a property exists on a given iteration of ngRepeat, then I recommend implementing a directive (smartRow) that checks for the property and adds the additional row when the property exists:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
           <th>Name</th>
           <th>Description</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="row in rows" smart-row="row">
            <td>{{row.name}}</td>
            <td>{{row.description}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

### Directive

```
  app.directive('smartRow', function($compile) {
    return  {
      restrict: 'A',
      transclude: 'element',
      link: function(scope, element, attr, ctrls, transcludeFn) {
        var model = scope.$eval(attr.smartRow);
        transcludeFn(function(clone) {
          element.after(clone);
          if (model.hasOwnProperty('price')) {

             var priceRow = angular.element('<tr price-row="' + model.price + '"></tr>');
             clone.after(priceRow);
             $compile(priceRow)(scope);
          }
        })
      }
    }
  });
```

The example solution was meant to demonstrate concepts that you could use in your own solution:

1. Using ngRepeat to loop over your array model and output HTML row elements
2. Using a custom directive to conditionally check for a property, and when it exists, insert another row element after it (the price row in my example).  The directive uses 'element' transclusion to achieve this.
3. Using the `$compile` service to manually compile the extra row and link it to the child scope created by `ngRepeat`.  In my example, I created a `tr` row with a `priceRow` directive, inserted it into the DOM, and then manually compiled it and linked it to the right scope.

Answer (score 0):

One idea to achieve this is use the `ngIf` directive ([see here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf)) to check for the `pick2`

You create two different set of `<tr>` one with something like `<tr ng-if="pick2">` and another like `<tr ng-if="!pick2">` so when you ngRepeat looped, it can decide which `<tr>` to be generated.

Another way is to create a custom directive where you can treat `pick2` as an input parameter for the custom directive to generate the appropriate `<tr>` markup.